# Press Enter after submitting HTTP request

Tags: http, keyboard, enter

After I send the http request, I need to press the "enter" key immediately.  Here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input id="approved_btn" value="Approve" class="btn" title="Approve" name="apv" type="submit" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com')">
</body>
</html>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  if(document.URL.indexOf("") >= 0) {document.getElementById('approved_btn').click();
}
   try {Typekit.load();} catch(e) {}
</script>
```

Right now it just opens Google in a new window and does not automatically press enter.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "press enter"? You cannot physically press a key by means of javascript on a "normal" system.

Comment: Ok.  Is it possible to add the "enter" command to the end of my http request?  I just want it to access www.google.com and press enter without any additional input from the user.

Comment: There is no "enter command". I know what you mean, but I also want you to understand how things work. You blindly rely on a key shortcut for a html button which might not always work as you expect. So I suggest you say _what_ it _really_ is you want to do instead of assuming _how_ you _might_ be able to achieve that...

Comment: I want to automatically press enter after accessing a web page.

Comment: As said: that is impossible. You need a physical robot to do that. And the effect of such an action is not predictable. But feel free to build such a system.

Comment: Ok I thought maybe some sort of code could press the enter button.  This is a limitation of programming languages?

Comment: An enter button is a physical button on the keyboard. How do you want to "press" that by software?

Comment: I do not want the software to press a physical button in real life.  That is ridiculous.

Comment: It is, indeed. That is why I asked what it _really_ is you want to happen. Which you did not answer to...

Comment: I am not trolling, I am trying to bring you to tell us what you are actually looking for. You either refuse to tell us (then why do you ask) or you are not able to actually point to what you really want to do (then we cannot help). Sorry if this infuriates you. But that is not my fault. Why don't you simply answer the question?

Comment: I answered your questions.  You keep harping on this robot idea. I tried putting up with it for a few comments but you are relentless with the negative behavior.

Comment: Ok, i am sorry I annoyed you. I hope you find out what you actually want to do so that others can understand and finally help. Good luck!

Comment: You removed my comment about you trolling.

Comment: Sorry, but please dont start accusing or insulting others. I have no way to remove your comment. Only you yourself have and maybe some administrator.

Comment: A fact was stated.  Our entire conversation is here EXCEPT for when I asked you to stop trolling me.

Comment: Unbelievable. Maybe you should start using your brain. _I have no way to remove someone elses comment. Just as you dont youself._

Comment: Let's try this again.  STOP TROLLING.

Comment: I will adress a moderator to sort this idiocy of your out. Bye. And _please_ calm down. Thanks. Bye.

Comment: I welcome the moderator to read the conversation we have been having.  You are a Troll, which is a term for someone who makes a deliberately offensive or provocative online posting with the aim of upsetting someone or eliciting an angry response from them.